# UglifyJS in Visual Studio 2015 only in release mode

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify, visual-studio-2015

I have configured [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/) in Visual Studio 2015 to minify my JavaScript files using [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS). Works fine.

However, I'd like this to happen only when I have Visual Studio in Release mode. In Debug mode I'd like to debug my JavaScript files and minified JavaScript is hard (impossible) to debug.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following to solve this problem using the ASP.Net 5 task runner.

My solution has the following folder hierarchy.

```
Solution
->wwwroot
->Scripts
  ->app.js
  ->Controllers
    ->controller1.js
    ->controller2.js
```

1.) A file watcher watches the Scripts directory and all sub folders.

2.) When a file change is detected all *.js files are copied from the script folder to my wwwroot directory in it's script folder.

3.) Then an uglify task runs on the script folder in the wwwroot directory, this minifies it into a single app.js file which is referenced by the html application.

The uglify task has the sourceMap option turned to turn which allows javascript debuggers to reference the scrips while in debug mode but when running not in debug mode the minified script is used.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

grunt.initConfig({
    copy: {
        main: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    src: ['Scripts/app.js', 'Scripts/Controllers/**'],
                    dest: 'wwwroot'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        my_target: {
            files: { 'wwwroot/app.js': ['wwwroot/Scripts/app.js', 'wwwroot/Scripts/**/*.js'] },
            options : {sourceMap : true}
        }
    },
    watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: ['Scripts/app.js','Scripts/**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['copy:main', 'uglify']
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy:main', 'uglify', 'watch:scripts']);
};
```